# C++ Builder F1007 Irreducible Expression Tree

Tags: c++builder-xe

I'm using C++ builder XE under Windows 7 pro.
I'm currently stepping through a function and want to inspect the value of some of my variables. There's a character array I've got, local to a function.

```
char result[80];
```

When I try to inspect this (with the code paused inside this function), a message pops up :

```
Error inspecting 'result': F1007 Irreducible expression tree
```

If I try to add a watch to this variable, it says `"???"`.

Any ideas what could cause this, and what it could mean in this context ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

[F1007 Irreducible expression tree (C++)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/F1007_Irreducible_expression_tree_%28C%2B%2B%29)

> An expression on the indicated line of the source file caused the code generator to be unable to generate code. Avoid using the expression. Notify Embarcadero if an expression consistently reproduces this error.

You are likely encountering a codegen bug and should file a [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com) ticket to Embarcadero for review.